# Testing Titanium's In-App Billing module for Android

Tags: android, titanium, keystore, signing, billing

Does anyone know how to properly test live android in app purchases in titanium debug mode?

Previously, I was successfully able to test live in-app purchases and create real transactions when debugging from Titanium Studio. That was because previously, I had incorrectly created my Google Play store listing using the development .apk as per:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123704/what-keystore-does-titanium-studio-use-to-build-android-app-during-development

and therefore, Google play had associated my dev_keystore with my in-app purchase codes.

However, when I then tried to build and upload my production release using a generated keypair/certificate as per:
wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Distributing+Android+apps

the Google Play store then (correctly) rejected my production candidate complaining that my APK had been signed with a different certificate to the one that was used in the original upload:

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. 
You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) 
with fingerprint(s): [ SHA1: ...:9D:47:9F ] and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK 
you uploaded have fingerprint(s): [ SHA1: ...:5D:E2:4E ]
```

As such, I had to delete my google play store listing and recreate it from scratch using the signed APK as described by the appcelerator guide referenced above.

This has now resulted in my in-app purchases becoming associated with the signed APK which means that now when I am testing a development build of the app and attempt to make an in-app purchase, I am greeted with:

```
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play
```

It is not a timing issue (I have waited 24 hours) as suggested by:
stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla

It is occurring because the dev_keystore in my development build doesn't match the certificate associated with the in-app purchase codes.

I imagine I might be able to get around this if Titanium studio allowed me to specify my apps certificate certificate when debugging as per:
http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-1214

In the interim, a testing workaround to debug purchases is that I have created an additional and separate 'test' duplicate google play application with identical in app purchases and associated it with my development .apk (instead of my signed apk). During testing, I then just need to change:

```
require('ti.inappbilling').setPublicKey(...)
```

to point to the test project instead of the real one. Then, when i'm comfortable with the payments, I will build using the real key.

This is a really sub-standard workaround and i'm hoping someone has a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

[TISTUD-3669](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-3669) adds the capability to specify the keystore used for non-production builds. Using this, you won't need the workaround you came up with.